# ExceptionHandling with Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-mvc

I have this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "*.xls", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String excel(Model model) {

    return "excel";
```

The excel wiew opens actually a ExcelViewer, which is build in method

```
 protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> map, WritableWorkbook ww, HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {

Class.writecontent
Class.writeMoreContent
```

Called methods write content to the Excel sheet and they can throw e.g biffException. How can I show a certain error page when Exception is occured?

I tried this

```
@Controller
public class ExcelController
{


    @ExceptionHandler(BiffException.class)
     public String handleException(BiffException ex) {

    return "fail";
    }


   @RequestMapping(value = "*.xls", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String excel(Model model) {

        return "excel";
    }

    }
```

But I'm getting the server's error message about Exceptions. Maybe a bean definition missing?

Answer (score 2):

`@ExceptionHandler`-annotated methods only handle exceptions thrown by handler methods in the same class. Your exception, on the other hand, is being thrown from within the `View`'s `render` method, at which point it's left the controller/handler layer.

Handling exceptions from within the view layer isn't well handled in Spring, mainly because it's hard to get it to work reliably with the servlet API, so I recommend you create a subclass of `ExcelView` and handle the exception in there.